# Select запрос с передачей list

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

Мне нужно передать список интов `items_id = [24,454,212,54]`  в `sql` запрос.

То есть допустим есть такой запрос:

`SELECT date FROM items where id in () group by date`

Мне нужно чтобы было так:

`SELECT date FROM items where id in (24,454,212,54) group by date`

Я пытался делать так:

```
query = 'SELECT date FROM items where id in (%s) group by date'
cursor.execute(query, items_id)
```

Но это не работает и выходит такая ошибка:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Смотрел документацию библиотеки  [pymysql](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html) и там написано что:

> If args is a list or tuple, %s can be used as a placeholder in the query.

Я не понимаю что я не делаю не так ? Я же как раз использую плейсхолдер и этот плейсхолдер поддерживает передачу списка.

Comment: cursor.execute(query, str(items_id)) не пробовали?

Comment: Попробовал ваш вариант не работает